# Probability using indicator function

Tags: probability

*There are 10 pairs of different socks in a drawer. You take 5 pairs out of it. What is the expected value of matching socks?*

Is it OK to use the indicator function as follows?

Let $X$ be the number of pairs that match. Let $I_i$ be the indicator function that takes $1$ if the the $i$ pair matches, and $0$ if it doesn't.

This allows to express $X$ as $X=I_1 + I_2 + ... + I_5$.

To calculate $I_i$, we use the probability of a random pair being a match, that is $I_i={10\over{20 \choose 2}}$.

Now we can use the linearity of the expectation to compute the result.

*Edit: Fix probability*

Comment: Hmmm... But what if two socks match, but are not in the same pair? I think decomposing $X$ into a sum of indicators is a good idea, but you might try a different kind of indicator.

Comment: The 10 pairs are different. So that means that one sock can only match with another one.

Comment: What, exactly, does $I_{1}$ indicate? From my understanding, you draw ten socks. $I_{1}=1$ iff the first two socks are a pair. Is this interpretation incorrect?

Comment: I don't think the problem is phrased clearly.  You want me to draw $10$ socks randomly (without replacement) from a collection of $20$.  I know each sock in the $20$ has a unique mate.  Are you then asking: "if you then group the $10$ chosen socks into pairs, in as much as you can, how many pairs do you expect to be able to make?"

Comment: @Micapps You draw 5 different pairs. That is, the first two socks are the first pair, the second two socks are the  second pair and so on until the fifth pair.

Comment: @jjjx Well in that case isn't the probability that $I_{1}=1$ exactly $\frac{1}{19}$? I.e. the probability that the second sock drawn matches the first?

Comment: @lulu no, you draw in pairs. That is, you form the pairs as you draw them. You don't draw 10 socks and you are allowed to form any pair.

Comment: To clarify:  you are asking "draw the $10$ socks in pairs.  How many of those pairs do you expect to actually match?"  Note:  the probability that a randomly selected pair is a match is $\frac {1}{19}$, as pointed out in another comment.

Comment: @jjjx To answer your question: Yes, you should use the probability of a random pair being a match, only it's not the number you wrote.

Comment: Crossed comments.  In that case, I agree with your methodology but you got the probability wrong.

Comment: Oh yeah, the probability is wrong. What I wanted to do is: there are $20 \choose 2$ possible pairs and only 10 matching pairs. And that's ${{10}\over{20 \choose 2}}$

Comment: @lulu now I'm curious, if the problem statement was like you initially interpreted it (we draw 10 socks, how many matching pairs there are), could we apply the same method?

Comment: Well, a similar method anyway.  Number your (matched) pair of socks and let $J_i$ be the indicator function which tells you if both members of the $i^{th}$ match were chosen.  Then you just have to calculate the probability that a fixed matched pair is chosen amongst your $10$.

Comment: @lulu would that probability be: the probability of drawing a matching pair is ${1\over{19}}$. As we draw 10 socks, the probability of $J_i=1$ is ${1\over{19}}{10 \choose 2}$?

Comment: Let me try again. We can draw ${20 \choose 10}$ different groups of shoes. If we fix the $i^{th}$ match, we can still have ${18 \choose 8}$ groups that contain the   $i^{th}$ match, so the probability is ${{18 \choose 8}\over{20 \choose 10}}$ ?

Comment: No.  Pick your pair, $(S_l,S_r)$.  The probability that $S_l$ is amongst the first $10$ is $\frac 12$ (it's either in the first $10$ or the remaining $10$).  Then you have $9$ slots left and $19$ socks to choose from, so the probability that $S_r$ is also taken is $\frac 9{19}$.  Thus the probability is $\frac 12*\frac 9{19}$.

Comment: Oh, didn't see your other comment.  Yes.  Your second method is correct.

Comment: Finally, thanks. I really need to practice a lot more if I ever expect to pass this course :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the method of indicator functions, but we may check your solution using basic counting methods. We count cases for each specific number of matching pairs. We will use derangements in our solution, which is notated by $!n.$

The total number of ways to draw the socks is $\frac{\dbinom{10}{2}\dbinom{8}{2}\dbinom{6}{2}\dbinom{4}{2}\dbinom{2}{2}}{5!} = 945.$

**Case 1:** $0$ matching pairs

Notice that since there are $0$ matching pairs, we can neglect this case in our expected value calculation.

**Case 2:** $1$ matching pair

$P(1) = \frac{5 \cdot !4}{945} = \frac{45}{945} = \frac{1}{21}.$

This contributes $1 \cdot \frac{1}{21}$ to the expected value.

**Case 3:** $2$ matching pairs

$P(2) = \frac{\dbinom{5}{2} \cdot !3}{945} = \frac{20}{945} = \frac{4}{189}.$

This contributes $2 \cdot \frac{4}{189}$ to the expected value.

**Case 4:** $3$ matching pairs

$P(3) = \frac{\dbinom{5}{3} \cdot !2}{945} = \frac{10}{945} = \frac{2}{189}.$

This contributes $3 \cdot \frac{2}{189}$ to the expected value.

**Case 5:** $5$ matching pairs

$P(5) = \frac{!0}{945} = \frac{1}{189}.$

This contributes $5 \cdot \frac{1}{189}$ to the expected value.

Our expected value is $\boxed{\frac{8}{63}}.$